# Integration Onesignal JS

Tags: onesignal

The idea is that the browser's direct permission request will appear after an ajax, and if user permission is given for notifications, the onesignal will return the user ID as I need to add it to my database for sending notifications customized. After ajax`s success, the onesignal is generating error in the image

[image]

I am using:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/assi.php',
        data: {ma_id:ma_id},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(retorno){

        var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
        OneSignal.push(["init", {
            appId: "*******************************",
            autoRegister: true ,
            promptOptions: {

            },
            welcomeNotification: {

            },
            notifyButton: {
              enable: true
            }
        }]);

        OneSignal.push(function() {
          OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
            console.log("The user's subscription state is now:",isSubscribed);
              OneSignal.push(function() {
                OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
                    console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);

                        $.post("../php/ma_notifica.php",
                        {
                            userId: userId,
                            ma_id: ma_id,
                            action: 'add'
                        }, function(data)
                        {

                        });
                });
              });
            });
          });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved

In public_html

`OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js`
`OneSignalSDKWorker.js`
`manifest.json`

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/assi.php',
        data: {man_id:man_id},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(retorno){

            var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
            OneSignal.push(["init", {
                appId: "************************************",
                safari_web_id: "web.onesignal.auto.********************",
                autoRegister: false ,
                promptOptions: {
                    actionMessage: "Receive Notifications?",
                    acceptButtonText: "Yes",
                    cancelButtonText: "no"
                },
                notifyButton: {
                  enable: true
                }
            }]);

            OneSignal.push(function() {
              OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
                console.log("The user's subscription state is now:",isSubscribed);
                  OneSignal.push(function() {
                    OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
                        console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);

                            $(this).text('Assinatura realizada com sucesso!');
                            $.post("../php/man_ass_notif.php",
                            {
                                userId: userId,
                                man_id: man_id,
                                action: 'add'
                            }, function(data)
                            {
                            });
                    });

                        //Send Tags
                            OneSignal.sendTags({
                                userId: userId,
                                user_type: man_id,
                            }).then(function(tagsSent) {
                                console.log(tagsSent);  
                                window.location.reload();   
                            });
                        //Send Tags
                  });
                });

              });
        }
    });
```